# how to add custom js into ALL admin models? django

Tags: javascript, django, model, customization

as this url mentioned
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/#assets-as-a-static-definition
I know that and it does work by adding each custom js into each model one by one BUT is there a way to add into ALL models so I do not have to add each model one by one?

Comment: why not make the base_site.html of your django admin extend and add all the custom js and css that you want to add. so that in admin all the pages will have the css and js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make an `admin` folder inside the `templates` folder and then create a `base.html` file or add below code in html file:

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
{% block extrahead %}
<<< add your css and js >>>
{% endblock %}
```

but make sure project app name must be above from `django.contrib.admin` in `INSTALLED_APP` of django settings

Comment: thx thx, this does work event hough I am not sure what you meant by app name must be above

Comment: this heads custom javascript in `head` tag, I need to add it before end of `body` tag